# Modify and Redirect URL using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url

I want to modify and then redirect this url:

`localhost:8080/backend/tb/?r=premium/site/testResponse?order_id=122113&status=success`

From `testResponse?order_id" to "testResponse&order_id`

Need help please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rule should work in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?/testResponse)\?(order_id=122113)(&.*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1&%2%3 [L,R=301]
```